# Is there any reason to keep Visual Studio 2013 installed after installing Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: visual-studio

Is there any reason to keep Visual Studio 2013 installed after installing Visual Studio 2015? If I'm collaborating with someone using VS2013, are there any known problems if I use VS2015?

Comment: It appears you are using C#.  No, you'd better keep VS2013 around for a while longer, you may well run headlong into one of the thousands of Roslyn integration bugs.  YMMV.

Comment: If you do not change the target Framework this will not be an issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see any reason to keep VS 2013. VS 2015 opens the same projects without problem.

I worked on the same project from 2 computers, one had VS 2013, other 2015 and didn't have any problem.